# Не работают любые команды discord.py

Tags: python, api, discord

Пытаюсь отвечать на команды игрока через `@bot.command`, но абсолютно ничего не работает. Вроде все верно делаю по вики, но не выходит

(в functions находится только `text_line()`)

```
import asyncio
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from functions import *

# Vars
client = discord.Client()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

# Functions
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    text_line("Discord bot")
    print("[!] Auth as {0.user}".format(client))
    print("[!] Latency: {0.latency}".format(client))
    print("[!] Activity: {0.activity}".format(client))
    print("[!] Nitro status: {0.user.premium_type}".format(client))

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def say(ctx):
    await ctx.send("hello")

# All messages
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        # Log bot messages
        print("[+] Bot send message in {0.channel}: {0.content}".format(message))
        return

    # Log player messages
    print("[+] New message from {0.author} in {0.channel}: {0.content}".format(message))

# Run
client.run(ur_token)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в том, что я забыл сменить `client.run` на `bot.run`